# Run java code in Java FXML markup file

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, have a quick look at it, I wonder if we can run java code inside FXML markup file? Like we can do it with jsp file with  block ?

Comment: I assume you mean "FXML"?

Comment: yes , sorry i was not clear enough

Comment: Could you edit the question and fix that? It will make it easier for others to find if they have the same question.

Comment: yes i will fix it, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. FXML is just markup that defines the layout. You can [express bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) in FXML, and technically you can include [Javascript for event handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#script_event_handlers), though I don't think anyone uses that for any real applications.

The dynamic aspects of the application are typically managed in a [controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers), which is a Java class. The FXML file can inject elements into the controller and nominate controller methods to be used as event handlers.

See the [introduction to FMXL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) for details.